# Does the "Custom Script" setting inside the sharepoint admin center affect modern sites (Communication or Team sites)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, script, sharepoint-admin-center

I did many tests and reading and i did not find a clear answer if the "Custom Script" setting inside the sharepoint admin center affect modern sites (Communication or Team sites). for example i did this test:-

1. inside the sharepoint admin center >> settings >> Custom Script >> i enable custom script as follow (i did this around 7 days ago):-
   [image]
2. then if:-

   - I (as the office 365 and sharepoint admin) create a modern site (communication or team)
   - **OR** any end user directly create a communication modern site or team modern site
   - **OR** and end user create an office 365 group.

the generated sharepoint modern sites will always have custom script disabled. so can i conclude that the "Custom Script" settings inside the sharepoint admin center does not affect modern sites (Communication or Team sites)?and when the setting mentioned "self-service created sites" this does not cover modern site created by end users or created through creating office 365 group?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The setting removes the Deny add customizes pages (although you also need to run `Set-SPOSite -denyaddandcustomizepages $false`). This allows you to do things like add a template to a site content type or add a SharePoint 2010 workflow.

Comment: seems i did not explain my question,, now i know what "Custom Script" will do, but my question if these settings is intended for modern sites, as per my test if i am allowing cusotm scripting inside the SP admin center, then all the modern sites will have custom script disabled...

Comment: "It depends". Should use you 2010 WFs? No, probably not, but you can. You can certain still use Site Content Types, so it is useful there.

You must still, even after setting the tenant settings, run the `Set-SPOSite` cmdlet on a per-site basis to disable this setting for modern sites.

Comment: but if i am enabling this per site collection and i am preventing it on the SP center admin, then the center admin setting will override the site collection setting as per this documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script where it mentioned the following `If you change this setting for a user's OneDrive or a classic team site, it will be overridden by the Custom Script setting in the admin center within 24 hours.` ...

Comment: also i found this question on MSDN https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/2692a69a-5d03-4676-902f-2a6148ca3cdc/confusing-results-for-our-quotcustom-scriptsquot-inside-our-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicessharepoint#0099b950-1afa-4b4c-b20b-7e27257f3508 where a moderator mentioned the following

Comment: `6. Only the three site templates “SharePoint MySites”, “Personal OneDrive sites” and “Any SharePoint site collection created based on self-service site creation” will have the same custom script settings in the sharepoint admin center. Custom scripts tenant-wide in the sharepoint admin center will not apply to modern site.` so is his answer wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong but again, it needs to be enabled on a per-site basis for modern sites, as well. I think though we've answered why you might do it.

Comment: can you please explain your answer in more details, as per my test where i am allow custom script on the SP admin center, and i created modern site and end users created modern sites,, but for all the modern sites when i run this command `Get-SPOSite -Identity $Url -Detailed | select DenyAddAndCustomizePages` i will get `enabled` for all the modern sites, and `enabled` here means that the "custom script" is disabled, although i am allowing it on the SP center admin..

Comment: As I stated, you must _also_ run `Set-SPOSite -DenyAddAndCustomizePages` along with enabling the tenant admin settings.

Comment: second point and again setting custom scripting at the site collection level is meaningless because it will be overridden (within 24 hours) to what we have set inside the SP center admin level...

Comment: Probably should take this to discussion, but again, if you _enable_ the admin center settings, and _disable_ the switch via PoSh, it will forever remain enabled.

Comment: so you mean if i am enabling custom scripting inside the SP admin center, then this will NOT automatically enable custom scripting inside modern sites unless i set it per site collection basis using this command `Set-SPOSite -Identity https://YourDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/YourSite -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0`? but for classic (non-modern sites) team sites (personal site or self-service created sites) , t

Comment: the custom scripting will be enabled automatically without having to run this command `Set-SPOSite -Identity https://YourDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/YourSite -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90754/discussion-between-sharepoint-testdev-and-trevor-seward).

Comment: now i tested the relation between the "custom settings" inside the sharepoint online admin and the modern site collections, and unlike what you mentioned there is not any relation between the two. For example i did this test, where inside our tenant i were allowing custom script for personal and self-service sites, then i created 2 modern communication sites, where their cusotm script were disabled, then i run a pnp script to enable the custom script on one of the modern sites >>

Comment: then i disable the cusotm script from the sharepoint central admin >> after one week i checked the custom script setting inside the modern sites and i found that the global setting did not override the custom script setting for modern sites (still cusotm script is enabled inside one and disabled inside the other), while the global setting had overridden the custom script settings for classic sites including the root site collection which had its custom script disabled...

Comment: You must manually disable it on Modern sites. The global settings simply prevent the setting from re-enabling in Modern sites.

Comment: i do not have to disable it manually inside modern sites, as the cusotm script will always be disabled on newly created modern sites regardless of the global setting... so now in our case we have custom script disabled globally (for 10 days now) >> but one of our modern sites have custom script enabled,, while for all the classic personal/self-service sites the global setting override them, so all the personal/self-service  classic sites currently have their cusotm script disabled!! but this is not the case for modern sites